# Importing a spreadsheet with infinity values from Excel

Tags: import, data, excel

I have imported a spreadsheet from Excel that I want to use as an adjacency matrix. I want to use this matrix as the argument in  `WeightedAdjacencyGraph`, so I have entered infinity symbols in the matrix where there are no edges linking two vertices.

However edges keep appearing in the graph with weight infinity assigned to them. The infinity symbol is imported from Excel as part of the spreadsheet.

If I use the spreadsheet as a list of lists it will construct a graph, but with unwanted edges. When I put the data in `MatrixForm`, it returns an error saying it is a not a non empty square matrix.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Have you checked in what format those infinities have been imported? I wouldn't be surprised if Mathematica simply didn't understand them...

Comment: Expressions wrapped in `MatrixForm` should not be given to functions as arguments. `MatrixForm` is wrapper that tells the front-end to do special formatting. Functions that test the heads of their arguments will almost always reject `MatrixForm` as invalid.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few formatting issues to take care of before you can use the data imported from Excel.

Let's start with a simple adjacency matrix:

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[ {{∞, 1, ∞}, {∞, ∞, 1}, {1, 1, ∞}} ]
```

which generates the following graph:

[image: original graph]

Let's export that adjacency matrix to an Excel file:

```
Export["adjmat.xlsx", {{∞, 1, ∞}, {∞, ∞, 1}, {1, 1, ∞}}]
```

---

Now we are in the same situation you are in, and we can import the data from the Excel file.

```
import = Import["adjmat.xlsx"][[1]]

(*Out: {{"Infinity", 1., "Infinity"}, {"Infinity", "Infinity", 1.}, {1., 1., "Infinity"}} *)
```

Notice two things: 1) I selected the first part of the list returned by export, which corresponds to the contents of the first sheet in the Excel file; 2) note that the `Infinity` values have been imported **as strings**.

We need to **turn those values into *Mathematica* expressions** before we can do anything with them:

```
converted = ToExpression[import]

(* Out: {{∞, 1., ∞}, {∞, ∞, 1.}, {1., 1., ∞}} *)
```

Now we can use that expression to generate the graph:

```
WeightedAdjacencyGraph[converted]
```

[image: graph from imported]